# Xamarin - Decrypting PDFs not supported?

Tags: c#, pdf, encryption, xamarin, syncfusion

I am using Syncfusion PDF library in my Xamarin project and I am trying to decrypt a PDF using the user password and I keep getting: System.NotSupportedException: Encrypted Document are currently not supported. All I do is:

```
PdfLoadedDocument loadedDocument = new PdfLoadedDocument(byteArray, "userPassword");
```

I can understand the meaning of the exception, but I was just wondering if there is any way of doing what I need to do.

Thanks!

Comment: You can replace the library with another one that supports encrypted PDF files on Xamarin platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encrypted PDF are not supported on **WinRT, Windows Phone, Xamarin, Universal Windows Platform and Silverlight**

```
public PdfLoadedDocument( 
   string filename,
   string password
)
```

> Remarks
>
> This constructor is not supported in WinRT, Windows Phone, Xamarin, Universal Windows Platform and Silverlight

Ref: http://help.syncfusion.com/cr/cref_files/wpf/pdf/Syncfusion.Pdf.Base~Syncfusion.Pdf.Parsing.PdfLoadedDocument~_ctor(String,String).html